# Daylight Savings Time Android 2.2

Tags: android, timezone, dst

When adjusting dates for a local timezone I've found a problem for a HTC Desire with Android 2.2.

1 nov 2011 shouldn't return mUseDST = true for GMT. But it does.

Did anyone else encounter this problem and how can this be solved?

Many thanks!

EDIT: For some strange reason this is working by the 2nd of November. Must be a bug, but now it works anyways.